# New academic cplex expired license message

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo

I've been trying to use cplex with pyomo to solve some LP, nevertheless when running I found the following error message

```
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.00] Creating model
[    0.02] Applying solver
The license for this version of CPLEX has expired.
ERROR: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", 568, solve
        Solver (cplex) returned non-zero return code (64)
ERROR: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", 571, solve
        See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
[    0.03] Pyomo Finished
ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
        Solver (cplex) did not exit normally
```

Moreover I realize that when typing "cplex" in the terminal the answer is

`The license for this version of CPLEX has expired.`

Nevertheless I just download the academic version of Cplex

1. IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.7

And the solver works when using oplide to run OPL models and with python when running the examples that came with the solver.

Before installing this version I uninstalled the previous cplex I had. 
I do not know how to make it work, I hope you could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Pyomo can use CPLEX via the interactive (`cplex.exe`), or the Python API.  It's not clear which one is being used in your case, so I'll try to cover both.

If you uninstall CPLEX Optimization Studio, it will not try to detect all of your local Python environments and remove the old CPLEX Python API from them.

You should be able to remove the old CPLEX Python API, by simply deleting the `cplex` folder from your `site-packages` directory (you should also delete the folder that looks something like `cplex-12.6.3.0-py2.7.egg-info`).  You'd have to do that for every Python version you have where the old CPLEX Python API was installed (e.g., 2.7 and 3.4, and any virtual environments too).

After doing that, you should re-install the CPLEX 12.7 Python API following the instructions [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html).  Hopefully that will get rid of your expired license messages *for Python*, and allow Pyomo to work with CPLEX.

You also mentioned that running the CPLEX interactive from the terminal also gives you a license expired message.  I would do a search of your file system for `cplex.exe` and remove any that aren't in the COS 12.7 installation directory.  You also need to make sure that the COS 12.7 installation directory is on your `PATH` as mentioned [here](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoInstallGuide.html#_cplex).